# Multi-clients on a server

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

For an application in C, i need to response more than one clients.

I setup the connection with a code like,

```
    bind(...);
    listen(...);
    while(1){
        accept(...);//accept a client
        recv(...);//receive something
        send(...);//send something to client
        bzero(buf);//clear buffer
    }
```

This works great when i have only one client. Other clients also can connect to the server but although they command something, server does not response back to clients who connected after the first client. How can i solve this problem?

Comment: `poll` or `select` would work too.  It'd be more nixy than threading, and easier to use than forking if data should be shared between clients (like, say, in a chat server).

Comment: @cHao Actually, i tried using select, but couldn't make it work. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a server using asynchronous, nonblocking connections.

Instead of a single set of data about a client, you need to create a struct. Each instance of the struct holds the data for each client.

The code looks vaguely like:

```
socket(...)
fcntl(...) to mark O_NONBLOCK
bind(...)
listen(...)
create poll entry for server socket.
while(1) {
    poll(...)
    if( fds[server_slot].revents & POLLIN ) {
        accept(...)
        fcntl(...) mark O_NONBLOCK
        create poll and data array entries.
    }
    if( fds[i].revents & POLLIN ) {
        recv(...) into data[i]
        if connection i closed then clean up.
    }
    if( fds[i].revents & POLLOUT ) {
        send(...) pending info for data[i]
    }
 }
```

If any of your calls return the error EAGAIN instead of success then don't panic. You just try again later. Be prepared for EAGAIN even if poll claims the socket is ready: it's good practice and more robust.

Comment: Do you need non-blocking sockets in order to use `poll`?  If not, what makes them better than blocking sockets (which would eliminate the need to check for EAGAIN), if we're using one thread for reading/writing?

Comment: @cHao: If you use blocking sockets with an asynchronous design your program will usually work but will suffer mysterious freezes when things go even slightly wrong.

Comment: @Zan: The very purpose of `poll` and `select` is to tell us what we can do without blocking.  If it tells us there's data to read, then reading some data shouldn't block.  In a single-threaded process, or if only one thread ever does socket I/O, `poll` should always be correct.  If it's lying, then the OS is broken.

Comment: @cHao: Then go implement your program with blocking sockets. Have fun making it work 100%.

Comment: @Zan: I have.  Several.  And it does work, 100%.  That's why i was asking about the reason behind using non-blocking sockets; i've never had a problem that was caused by inappropriate blocking.  I was wondering what problems they solve that aren't already solved by `select`/`poll` and a designated I/O thread.

Comment: @cHao: And it worked on Solaris, BSD, Linux 2.2 - 2.6, MacOS X and HPUX?

Comment: @Zan: `select` worked on Linux (1.2, 2.0, 2.2 and 2.6) and Windows (98SE and XP).  `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` (Windows' equivalent of `poll`) worked fine on XP.  Haven't messed with `poll` on Linux yet, but i assume it's at least as usable as `select`.

Comment: @cHao: All I can say is that if you never ran into a OS that reported readable or writable on select and then blocked, you have gotten very lucky. Since the result is to hang the entire application until that client disconnects it is always safer to use non-blocking sockets.

Answer (score 0):

`i need to response more than one clients.`

Use [Threading](http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/threads/threads.c.php).

Comment: Depends on how many clients the software needs to handle.  One thread per client can get real big, real fast.

Comment: Also, threading can be difficult to get right, and difficult to debug.  Multiplexing with select() or poll() or similar is often simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want your main thread to only do the accept part, and then handle the rest to another thread of execution (which can be either a thread or a process).

Whenever your main thread returns from "accept", give the socket descriptor to another thread, and call accept again (this can be done with fork, with pthread_create, or by maintaining a thread pool and using synchronization, for instance condition variables, to indicate that a new client has been accepted).

While the main thread will handle possible new clients incoming, the other threads will deal with the recv/send.